# Using Pythagorean Identities to Solve for Values

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing homework for my trig class, and it's asking for us to use Pythagorean identities to solve for other trig values. I got through the first 10 fine, but I'm stuck on the last three. My teacher has specified that we have to use the pythagorean trig identities... aka:

- $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$
- $1 + \tan^2 \theta  = \sec^2\theta$
- $\cot^2 \theta + \ 1 = \csc^2 \theta$

The questions are:

1. Given that $x$ is in the first quadrant and $\csc x=1$, what is $\sin x$?
2. Given that $x$ is in the first quadrant and $\sec x=\sqrt{2}$, what
   is $\cos x$?
3. Given that $x$ is in the first quadrant and $\sin x=\frac{1}{2}$,
   what is $\csc x$?

I have no idea where to start using the Pythagorean Identities. Help?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use the Pythagorean identities. Here's a reminder that should help: $\csc \theta = 1 / \sin \theta$ and $\sec \theta = 1 / \cos \theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Along with pythagorean identities, there are also elementary identities like, $$\begin{align*}\cos x &= \dfrac{1}{\sec x}\\ \sin x&=\dfrac{1}{\csc x}\end{align*}$$ use them to get your result. And, note that, you don't need to know in which quadrant does $x$ lie and so on to use these identities.

However, if you were asked to calculate $\sin x$ from $\sec x$, you do require that fact to fix the sign of $\sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the point of this question is to  get you to practice using the Pythagorean identities to transform values. Yes, it would be easier in these cases to just use the elementary identities, but this is a more "how you got there" problem than a "what's the answer" problem.

user21436 was right that the elementary identities will play a role. But in case anyone is interested in seeing how to solve these explicitly, here's a solution to problem 1:

- $\csc{x} = 1$
- $\csc^{2}{x} = 1^{2} = 1$
- $\cot^{2}{x} + 1 = 1$
- $\frac{\cos^{2}{x}}{\sin^{2}{x}} + 1 = 1$
- $\frac{\cos^{2}{x}}{\sin^{2}{x}} + 1 = \sin^{2}{x} + \cos^{2}{x}$
- $\cos^{2}{x} + \sin^{2}{x} = \sin^{2}{x}(\sin^{2}{x} + \cos^{2}{x})$
- $1 = \sin^{2}{x}$

Assuming $x$ is in the first quadrant:

- $1 = \sin{x}$

If $x$ weren't in the first quadrant, $\sqrt{1} = \sqrt{\sin^{2}{x}}$ would result in two solutions for $\sin{x}$: $1$ and $-1$.

Keep in mind that there are many other ways to solve this problem using the Pythagorean identities!

Comment: Except $\,\sin x = 0\,$ is not a solution to $\,\csc x = 1\,$. There is no good reason to unearth a question fully answered $10+$ years ago, but if you decide to do it anyway then at least make sure you post correct math.

Comment: Thanks for the catch dxiv! I'll make sure to double-check my work in the future. I updated this answer to avoid that error.

Comment: Looks good now. For completeness, you may want to add a note that the last step $1 = \sin^2 x$ $\implies 1 = \sin x$ uses the assumption that $x$ is in the first quadrant. (The assumption is not necessary when proving $\csc x = 1 \implies \sin x = 1$ directly from definitions.)

Comment: Good idea. I just added that. Thanks again!